# error : NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Tags: python, solaris

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
username = 'joe'

# generate passphrase
pw_length = 6
phrase = subprocess.check_output(['pwgen', str(pw_length), '1'])
phrase = phrase.decode('utf-8').strip()

dev_null = open('/dev/null', 'w')
passwd = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'passwd', user], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=dev_null.fileno(),
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
passwd.communicate( ((phrase + '\n')*2).encode('utf-8') )
if passwd.returncode != 0:
    raise OSError('password setting failed')
```

how do i fix this error :

```
bash-3.00# python ./pass2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pass2.py", line 6, in ?
    phrase = subprocess.check_output(['pwgen', str(pw_length), '1'])
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

Comment: import subprocess?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Subprocess is a module. You need to import it.

Put this as the second line in your file: `import subprocess`

Comment: now i am getting this `phrase = subprocess.check_output(['pwgen', str(pw_length), '1'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`

Comment: @munish Start a new question. Don't just edit your original question to ask a new one once the initial question was solved. You should accept jknupp's answer and ask a new question about your `check_output' error. I rolled back your edit so you could ask a new question.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano,munish:  Actually, he shouldn't. He shouldn't get into the habit of posting on stackoverflow as soon as he runs into an error. But I'm with you on not continuing the other discussion here (this is mainly directed at the OP of course :p).

Comment: @Keyser Good point. Debugging should always come before posting on here.